# Making Foreign Language Characters AJAX Safe

Tags: php, json, ajax

```
$sampleText = "Episode 8 - Dansk dokumentarserie. Jørgen og John drar ut for å";
```

I need to convert it to json and encode it in a way to make it AJAX safe.

I tried following encoding :

```
//$name = htmlentities(utf8_encode($sampleText), ENT_QUOTES);
//$name = htmlentities($sampleText, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
//$name = htmlentities(utf8_encode($sampleText), ENT_COMPAT);
```

Sometimes it works but in some cases I get `\.` which makes json invalid.

Example : Gäster är kulturminster Alice `\.` Bah Kuhnke och komikern William Spetz.Kategori: TalkShow `\.`.

Invalid JSON due to string `\.` :

```
[{"name" : "Humortalkshow."}, 
 {"name" : "Temat 2013 var \."}, 
 {"name" : "Talkshow \."}]
```

Could you please help me encode the foreign characters in a proper way.

Comment: Just switch to UTF-8 and use the built-in `json_encode()` function.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález You mean, I simply use `utf8_encode($sampleText)` ?

Comment: Nope, that's the convoluted way to do it. If you use UTF-8 everywhere you don't need to convert back and forth. In 2015, the only reason to use any other encoding is having to support a legacy project that cannot be upgraded.

Comment: Can you please write a sample code ?